# How to make QRadioButton self centric

Tags: python, pyqt

With three radio buttons created and assigned to the same layout:

```
radio1 = QtGui.QRadioButton("button 1")
radio2 = QtGui.QRadioButton("button 2")
radio3 = QtGui.QRadioButton("button 3")

layout.addWidget(radio1)
layout.addWidget(radio2)
layout.addWidget(radio3)
```

all three "magically" start to act in unison. Clicking one unchecks two others.
But I would like each to be independent. So all three could be checked or unchecked at the same time. What I would like to get is checkbox type of behavior. How to achieve it?

Comment: Did you read documentation ? There should be answer.

Comment: BTW: I found answer in less then 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.radio1.setAutoExclusive(False)
self.radio2.setAutoExclusive(False)
self.radio3.setAutoExclusive(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case, it looks like you would be better off using checkboxes.

```
check1 = QtGui.QCheckBox("button 1")
check2 = QtGui.QCheckBox("button 2")
check3 = QtGui.QCheckBox("button 3")

layout.addWidget(check1)
layout.addWidget(check2)
layout.addWidget(check3)
```

Comment: Radio buttons are looking better to me.